# DataGridView checkbox column - value and functionality

Tags: c#, datagridview, crystal-reports, checkbox

Here is a reference the old SO question.

[DataGridView checkbox column - value and functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237829/datagridview-checkbox-column-value-and-functionality/1395215#1395215)

I need to know, how would I get the information from a specific cell, so that i may further make the crystal report of the checked rows of datagridview.

Thanks.
-nav

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the rows_with_checked_column object created by SwDevMan81 in the accepted answer to the other thread, then loop through those rows to get a comma-delimited list of unique IDs, then use those IDs in your Crystal Reports record selection formula.

rpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{ATable.AnID} In [" & stringofIDs & "]"