# Check a checkbox inside Gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, datagridview, checkbox

I want to check a check-box which is inside Gridview programmatic on click of a button

Comment: try to follow this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237829/datagridview-checkbox-column-value-and-functionality

Regards.

Comment: You mean all of the checkBoxes on a button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].DataGridView[0, i].Value = false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the location of the cell then you can set it as

```
datagridview1[0,2].Value = true;// this should be a checkboxcolumn
```

OR

```
datagridview1["chkboxcolumnName",2].Value = true;
```

This will cause the checkbox to be checked for that particular cell.

Hope this is what you meant else please edit the question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way (by subscribing to two events):

```
    void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object obj, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) //compare to checkBox column index
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cbx = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(cbx.Value) && (bool)cbx.Value == true)
            {                 
                //checkBox is checked - do the code in here!
            }
            else
            {
               //if checkBox is NOT checked (unchecked)
            }
        }
    }
```