# how to add selected rows of datagridview to a datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I started working with Windows Form Application recently. In a datagridview `DatagridView1` I am displaying some data from a datatable `dt1`.

```
DatagridView1.DataSource=dt1;
```

I have added a column in `DatagridView1` named `selectRows` of type `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn`.

I want to add the selected rows of the `DatagridView1` to another datatable. 
I have a button `btn_Select`, On button click I am getting the selected rows in a string format using following code:

```
private void btn_Select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            string data = string.Empty;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DatagridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value != null &&
                       Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[0].Value) == true)
                {
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (cell.OwningColumn.Index != 0)
                        {


                            data += (cell.Value + " "); // do some thing
                        }
                    }
                    data += "\n";
                }
            }
       }
```

But I want to select the whole row, not just text.

Comment: you can select individual cells in a row and add data accordingly...for e.g. Row.Cells[n] where n is 0,1,2 etc

Comment: I tried to use {foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells[0])} but its giving me error,  'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this. This is exactly what you want.

[DataGridView checkbox column - value and functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237829/datagridview-checkbox-column-value-and-functionality)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DataBoundItem` property to get the data in the entire row. With `DataTable.ImportRow` method you can import the selected rows data into a different table.

Sample Code:

```
DataRow datarow = null;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if(Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value) == true)
        {
        datarow = ((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row;
        dt.ImportRow(datarow);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How I can Use the DataBoundItem property to get the data in the entire row.

Comment: @Rocky - see the sample code. Assuming you filled your datatable from an database, you can access the data bound to the entire row using DataBoundItem property.