# How to get IDs of only checked rows of a datagridview

Tags: c#, database, checkbox, datagridview

I have a datagridview that contains list of subjects populated from Subject table from database.Columns include

- Select(checkbox),
- SubjectId,
- SubjectName,
- SubjectGroup.

Now I want if a user Selects on any of the desired rows, the corresponding SubjectId's should be added to a **List**. I have made and inserted into the desired table in the database.
The problem is that the new column of checkboxes I have added to this datagridview is not being detected.

My code is:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvSubjectsOpted.Rows)
        {

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(gvSubjectsOpted.SelectedRows[0].Cells["SelectId"].Value=true))
            {
                olist.Add(gvSubjectsOpted.SelectedRows[0].Cells["SubjectId"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title... see [Should questions include "tags" in their title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not.

Comment: Is the data bounded? or added individually?

Comment: The data is bounded with SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 11):

Late to the party.  I had the same issue with trying to get the checkbox column by name, use the index instead.  Here is a linq example assuming the checkbox is column 0 and the stored values for TrueValue and FalseVale are true and false respectively.

```
        var checkedRows = from DataGridViewRow r in gvSubjectsOpted.Rows
            where Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[0].Value) == true
            select r;

        foreach (var row in checkedRows)
        {
            olist.Add(row.Cells["SubjectId"].Value.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise this is an old post but I came across it and didn't think it was really answered in an efficient way so I thought I would add my method.

I have a similar block in my windows app. I read the values from the grid when the user clicks a button, and I want to know which rows they checked. As the checkboxes are in Cell 0 and the data I want is in Cell 1, I use the following code. Note the cast: it is important as it allows us the use the Where clause and therefore just a single line of code to get the collection of data. I could use the name of the cells instead of magic index numbers but then it would not fit your app so I put numbers instead (you should use names)

```
    var checkedRows = dataGridView
        .Rows
        .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
        .Where(x => x.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "1")
        .Select(x => x.Cells[1]);
```

Note that this will give you an IEnumerable of type DataGridViewCell. If you want you can either add something like `.Value.ToString()` to the select or do this when you use your collection.

Comment: Throws an exception on not checked rows.

Comment: Nonchecked rows are null, so just change the where to: .Where(x => x.Cells[0].Value!= null)

Answer (score 1):

You question is similar to another SO question.

Check the answer of this [Datagridview checkboxcolumn value and functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237829/datagridview-checkbox-column-value-and-functionality).

Comment: Man,that question doesn't have the exact answers.Could u plz mould that into my requirements?Plz

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach(GridViewRow r in gvSubjectsOpted.Rows)
{
    GridViewCheckBoxColumn c = r.cells[0].Controls[0] as GridViewCheckBoxColumn;
    if(c.Checked)
    {
      //Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hitech Salia, it gives an error of FindControl...also SubjectId is my column name which I want to get in case it's row is checked by the user.

Answer (score 0):

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {   
        string subjId;   
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();   
        for (int i = 0; i < gvSubjectsList.Rows.Count; i++)   
        {   
       bool Ischecked =Convert.ToBoolean(gvSubjectsList.Rows[i].Cells["Select"].Value);    
            if (Ischecked == true)   
            {   
                subjId = gvSubjectsList.Rows[i].Cells["SubjectId"].Value.ToString();   
                lines.Add(subjId);   
            }   
    }
    comboBox1.DataSource = lines;     

    }
```

//the most important thing is to set 'true' and 'false' values against newly added checkboxcolumn instead of '0' and '1'...that is,

CBColumn.FalseValue = "false";
CBColumn.TrueValue = "true";