# How can I tick or untick a checkbox in a datagridview using White

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, white-framework

I have a WinForms app, that displays a DataGridView.  It is automatically populated from a BindingSource, and contains several rows of data.  The columns include the standard things like strings.  Some of these columns are CheckBoxes.

`Name | User | Admin
 ----   ----   -----
 John |   X  |

 Fred |      |   X`

I am writing some automated tests using TestStack.White.  I can read the existing state of the CheckBoxes without issue.

How do I set or clear the checkboxes?
I've tried:

1. `Table.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = true;`

Fails because the underlying row/cell is deleted before White can read back the current value.

And also:

2. `Table.Rows[0].Cells[1].SetValue(true);`

Fails to set the new value.

Answer (score 1):

Because `TestStack.White` cannot access the underlying object model you will have to come up with a *New* button or *Reset* button. Or some GUI way (with logic) to clear the Checkbox values by setting the `BindingSource's` boolean fields to false.

Here is some psuedo code to illustrate.

```
private void New_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{
   DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgv.DataSource;
   dt[1]["IsAdmin"].value = false;
   //In ASP.Net you also need a dgv.Bind(); //this is not necessary in winforms
}
```

There should already be a way in your system to test with Checkboxes cleared, it should be consistent with how the end user currently do it.

Comment: It feels wrong that I have to write extra code in the application to be able to test the UI, Fortunately, I have the source code, so I can do this.

Comment: You should not need to, there should already be a way in your system.. what you are testing with the checkboxes should reflect the end user steps/actions that you're testing. If the user can untick a cell with a click then you should be able to do that with White, maybe this code should be in a CellClick event.

Comment: But that's the problem, with White, I can't programatically click the check box.  If I am manually testing, then of course, the checkbox can be ticked, but this is an automated test, and the automation tool doesn't seem able to click a specific checkbox that is part of a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

My this be an helpful way to set values? [DataGridView checkbox column - value and functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237829/datagridview-checkbox-column-value-and-functionality):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    row.Cells[CheckBoxColumn1.Name].Value = true;
}
```

Or what is your `Table` for an Object?

Comment: I suspect this does a string to column number lookup, and then does option 1 in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the check boxes in c# has a property '**Checked**'. And even though it's in the DataGridView, I believe the property of the controls remains the same.

So, can you try this instead

```
Table.Rows[0].Cells[1].Checked = true;
```

**Resources**: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/checkbox-in-C-Sharp3/

Answer (score 0):

Because your `DataGridView` is bound to `BindingSource`, you should change the Boolean value in `BindingSource` rather than through the `dataGridView` control.

Comment: How do I access the ``BindingSource`` from just the UI?  Remember, this is  a  UI test, so has no access to the internals of the code.

Comment: If you do UI test then you should just work with keyboard and mouse rather trying to change programmatic.

Comment: correct, so how do I do that, when the only UI I can access is the ``DataGridView`` ? TestStack.White only has access to the ``DataGridView``, not ``BindingSource``,

Comment: `DataGridView` has `DataSource` property, Can TestStack.White access this property?

Answer (score 0):

I also could not extract checkbox that belongs to datagridviewcheckboxcolumn neither from cell nor from row, and finally ended up with a hack using mouse, something like this:

```
Rect bounds = table.Rows[rowNo].Cells[colNo].Bounds;
Point center = new Point(bounds.X + bounds.Width / 2, bounds.Y + bounds.Height / 2);
Mouse.Instance.Click(center);
```